# Tire + Elasticsearch: How to search ranges of values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

Love Tire and elasticsearch so far but can't figure out how to search values between ranges like:

- age_from  age_to
- 18 to 20

And return all Profile's where the age is between these 2 ranges?
I have a integer column Profile.age

So far incomplete function

```
def self.search(params)

    #, default_operator: "AND
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
      query do
        should { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
        should { integer age_to[:age_to] } if params[:age_to].present?
      end
      to_curl
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
query do
    should { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
    should { range :age, { gte: params[:age_from], lte: params[:age_to] } } if params[:age_to].present? && params[:age_from].present?
end
```